# Django South Skip Some Migration Files

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have two servers one is development and one is production. On the development the app migration is `0012` on the production it is currently `0006`. For some reason we still don't want to migrate the migrations from `0007 -> 0011` but we do want to migrate the `0012` on production as well, i know i can do this to migrate specific file:

```
manage.py migrate apps.my_app 0012
```

My question is will south be broken if there is gap in migration files? If yes how to handle this particular case then so that in future when we want to migrate in between migration files (which are being skipped for now) we can do it without breaking anything?

Comment: You might want to consider `--fake 0011` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have gaps in migrations as South assumes these are sequential. I would do:

1. Migrate development back to `0006`.
2. Create a new migration `0007` that does what `0012` does and apply it to both development and production.
3. Create new migration(s) for the original `0007` till `0011` changes and apply those to development (and production when ready).

In the future I'd recommend using branches and only merge those branches (including migrations) when you're ready to have them on development and production.

Comment: i like yours idea of branches but for now we have separate git repositories for both servers. But i am still understanding your answer at the moment.